# Getting variable names of desired values in R

Tags: r, subset

My data (group) has 300 variables showing which group it belong to in the second row..There are a total of 6 groups

```
2017 2766 1737 1745 1747 1883 1884 1821 1900 ......
3    4    6    3    3    3    3    3    3    ......
```

If I do this:

```
group=="6"
```

It will show if the variables are true or false if they belong to group 6 as below

```
2017  2766  1737 1745  1747  1883  1884  1821  1900  ..............
FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ..............
```

I am trying to get it list out all the variables which belong to individual group.
For example I want to ask what variables belong to group 6

I tried this but it gave a null results:

```
names(group=="6")
```

I then want to save the names into a csv.

Comment: What was your question?

Comment: Please study [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1412059). You need to share your data in a way that lets us see your exact data structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
colnames(group)[which(group=="6")]
```

when group is a data.frame or else

```
names(group)[which(group=="6")]
```